# Default Folder Order in Gnome

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, nautilus, defaults

How do I set the default folder order in `Gnome`? I'm talking about setting 'type order' as default so the folders will always be listed at the top, and other files after them.

Here is the image:

[image]

You see that everything is listed by the type, and I want this to be the default order so when I reboot, it won't reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will be able to achieve this by opening nautilus preferences as follow:
open a nautilus window > click on "files" from top menu > preferences ([as showed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224970/nautilus-missing-menubar-in-12-10#224975))

And then from there setup the Default view. Specifically Arrange items: by type

[image]